# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files

Tags: java

My application runs perfectly on my pc HP DV7-Pvillion, but when I put the jar ofmy application and its libraries on other machines all running  except the generation of PDF files. in my the log files I have folowing error : **Error compiling report java source files**

ps: I am working on netbeans 6.8 and I use iRaport

I should mention that my application runs perfectly on my workstation which is installed netbeans
but if I try to run the jar on another machine that does not work generation.

Could you give me an explanation for this?

Comment: It's difficult to answer with the amount of information you have provided. _Error compiling report java source files_ this can be due to various reasons. Please post stacttrace, your specific portion of code etc.

Comment: It is likely that the classpath is not correct (some jars are missing). That's at least my experience.

Comment: Include the Jar jasper-compiler-jdt in the lib folder

Answer (score 4):

Include the Jar jasper-compiler-jdt in the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge the **jasper-compiler-jdt** is now distributed as **ecj...jar**. Therefore, if you cannot find the **jasper-compiler-jdt** in your **jasper reports library**, search for **ecj...jar** and include that in your project.